# ReactJS - MouseClick gets triggered without a click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React.JS and trying to create a click event on an element inside a rendered component.

Here is my code:

```
class InputPanel extends React.Component{

  handleClick(i,j) {    
    this.props.dispatch(actions.someMethod());
   // e.preventDefault();
  }  

  render() {
    const { dispatch, board } = this.props;

    return(
   <div>           
      {
        board.map((row, i) => (
        <div>{row.map((cell, j) => <div className="digit" 
                                onClick={this.handleClick(i,j)}>{cell}</div>)}</div>
      ))
    }
  </div>
   );

 }
};
```

My problem is that "handleClick" gets triggered after page load without any mouse clicked!

I've read about React.JS lifecycle and thought about registering to click event in `componentDidMount` method, but i'm really not sure about it:

1. Is there any easier way ? (or: Am I doing something wrong that triggers click ?)
2. If adding `componentDidMount` method is the right way - how can I get the element I create in `render` method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **not** use `.bind` when passing the callback as a prop. There’s a [ESLint rule](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md) for that. You can read more about how to pass callback without breaking React performance [here](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/659).

Summary:

1. make sure you aren’t calling functions but pass functions as handlers in your props.
2. make sure you do not create functions on every render, for that, you need to bind your handlers in parent component, pass correct the required data (such as indices of iteration) down the child component and have it call the parent’s handler with the data it has

Ideally you’d create another component for the rows and pass the callback there. Moreover, ideally you’d bind the onClick in the parent component’s constructor (or componentWillMount). Otherwise every time render runs a new function is created (in both anonymous function handler `() => { this.onClick() }` and `this.onClick.bind` and defeat React’s vdom diff causing every row to rerender every time.

So:

```
class InputPanel extends React.Component{
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(i,j) {    
    this.props.dispatch(actions.someMethod());
   // e.preventDefault();
  }  

  render() {
    const { dispatch, board } = this.props;

    return(
   <div>           
      {board.map((row, i) => <div>
          {row.map((cell, j) => <Digit 
            onClick={this.handleClick})
            i={i} 
            j={j}
            cell={cell}
          />)}
      </div>)}
  </div>
   );

 }
};

class Digit extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick() {
    this.props.onClick(this.props.i, this.props.j);
  }

  render() {
    return <div 
      className="digit"
      onClick={this.handleClick}
    >{this.props.cell}</div>
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you have a mistake.. Isn't this suppose to be like: <Digit onClick={this.handleClick}) i={i} j={j} />)}</div>

Comment: I also found that instead of {cell} in render you need to create "cellProp" on "Digit" like:
'cellProp={cell}'

Comment: @ohadinho correct, I was concentrated on the callback issue so forgot about the `cell` prop – also it’s probably a good idea to `bind` the callback in the `<Cell>` component too.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are calling this.handleClick() function instead of providing a function definition as onClick prop.

Try changing the div line like this:

```js
<div className="digit" onClick={ () => this.handleClick(i,j) }>{cell}</div>
```

Also you have to bind this.handleClick() function. You can add a constructor and bind all the member functions of a class there. that's the best practice in ES6.

```js
constructor(props, context) {
  super(props, context);
  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: @Pranesh onClick prop takes a function reference as its value. But onClick={this.handleClick(i,j)} is a function call. If there were no arguments to be passed into the function, we could just give onClick={ this.handleClick } but since there are arguments (i, j) too be passed, the best way to do is give an anonymous function definition () => this.handleClick(i,j) and then pass it as the onClick prop value so that onClick will be assigned a reference to that anonymous function.

Comment: Creating a new anonymous function when passing a prop will circumvent React diffing mechanism causing the rows to always rerender.

Answer (score 1):

You call this function in render. You should only transfer function and `bind` params.

```
onClick={this.handleClick.bind(null,i,j)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.bind()`.

```
class InputPanel extends React.Component{

  handleClick(i,j) {    
    this.props.dispatch(actions.someMethod());
   // e.preventDefault();
  }  

  render() {
    const { dispatch, board } = this.props;

    return(
   <div>           
      {
        board.map((row, i) => (
        <div>{row.map((cell, j) => <div className="digit" 
                                onClick={this.handleClick.bind(null,i,j)}>{cell}</div>)}</div>
      ))
    }
  </div>
   );

 }
};
```

Comment: This way, every time render is run, `.bind` will create a new function making performance worse (re-rendering the rows every time).