# ReactJS handleClick triggers without clicking when the page loads

Tags: reactjs, button

React newbie here. I just want a simple button that does something on click. But the handleClick function gets triggered when the page loads.

I've found this [ReactJS - MouseClick gets triggered without a click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39705916/reactjs-mouseclick-gets-triggered-without-a-click), but is there really no other way to make it work without creating an extra class?

This is my code:

```
class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.state = {
            open: false,
        };

        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick(){
        console.log('The link was clicked.');
        history.push("/zeitsammler/homepage");
    }

    render() {
       return (
            <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
                <div style={styles.container}>
                    <RaisedButton label="Login" style={btnStyle} onClick={this.handleClick()} />
                </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing a function to the `RaisedButton` component, but rather executing it, change it to:

```
<RaisedButton label="Login" style={btnStyle} onClick={this.handleClick} />
```

Comment: Well that was simple. How did i miss this... Thanks a lot!